# зАДАЧА ПО ПАЙТОН только Python

Tags: python

Диофантово уравнение Даны числа a , b , c , d . Выведите в порядке возрастания все целые числа от 0 до 1000 включительно, которые являются корнями уравнения a⋅x3+b⋅x2+c⋅x+d=0 .
Входные данные Вводятся целые числа a , b , c и d . Все числа не превосходят по модулю 30000 .
Выходные данные Выведите ответ на задачу. Если в указанном промежутке нет корней уравнения, то ничего выводить не нужно.

*a = int(input())

b = int(input())

c = int(input())

d = int(input())

for x in range (1001):

if a * x ** 3 + b * x**2 c * x + d == 0:
print (x)*
Укажите мне ошибку

Comment: Вы забыли задать вопрос.

Comment: И тему поменять бы